# Difference between CFArray and NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, signal-processing

I'm looking for an easier way to manipulate audio buffers on the iPhone. Mainly I'm trying to avoid pointer issues and array count issues with C, but don't want to be slowed down by number objects like NSNumber or NSInteger which I would have to use with NSArray.

I've come across CFArray which seems like it might be a nice middle ground. Am I correct in this assumption? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not really. `CFArray` is basically the same as `NSArray`, you can even cast between the two, this is called [toll-free bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html).

`CFArray` (and its mutable counterpart) does allow you to specify your own callback functions for retaining and releasing the objects (pointers) in your array, which would allow you to store arbitrary pointers (not just `NSObject`s) in the array and implement your own memory management scheme, but I doubt that this would result in any real performance gains. For your use case, C arrays are probably the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If performance and memory size are of any concern, which they likely will be for real-time audio processing, stick to plain C arrays, and learn how to code array passing and access correctly.

You need to handle audio in C arrays anyway, as the iOS Audio Queue and Audio Unit APIs pass audio data using C arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like C-style and want to use some need object oriented class-style I would really recommend to use C++, eg. std::vector or similar.
Do not use Objective-C for audio it's not made for signal processing! Obj-C is great for dealing with UI's and connecting objects within a signaling system. Any kind of 'real' computation should always be done in C or flat C++.